# msql password chancing_sha2_password plugin

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I can change the password of root@localhost user from auth_socket ==> mysql_native_password, but other users can not change to mysql_native_password;

mysql.session, mysql.sys, debian-sys-maint and phpmyadmin (when I installed phpmyadmin mysql said: `ERROR 1819 (HY000) at line 1` error so I couldn't create a record in the database)

I want all users to be able to change mysql_native_password from chancing_sha2_password plugin because; if I can't change plugin methods; I can't use phpmyadmin or other 3 party app.

(mysql said:ERROR 1819(HY000) at line 1)

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             | *91EA82EFAD0677E20FDAEC7F11E15244530996F6 | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *70B3E55DA437B329F2F1A90C66719B666CBF4B9E | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed!!!
firstly;install phpmyadmin and add to apache2 and login mysql password.
On the phpmyadmin screen, the mysql password will give an error, but accept the statement and complete the setup. Then type the following code in the mysql command window!
so far

```
ALTER USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'TestPassword123*-';
```